# Draw cards expectation

Tags: probability

Assume if I have $k$ different cards. Each time I draw them, I replace them. Can you tell me how to calculate the expectation of having drawn full $k$ different cards?

I have figured out to calculate the expectation separately. For example, I can assume that I have drawn the first type of card, and calculate the expectation (that is, the number of cards needed to be drawn to get the second type card, which can be any type except the first type that have be drawn). And calculate the similar third expectation, up to $k$th expectation. But I don't know how to calculate the separate expectation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just calculate $E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{k} ip(X=i)$ .$X$ is the card that's unique to the ith draw.

Comment: If you are looking for the expected number of draws until you have seen each card at leasr once, please look at the *Coupon Collector's Problem* (Wikipedia). But I am not sure what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use Indicator Random Variables.   Let $X_i$ indicate that a unique card was drawn on draw $i$.   That is: 
$$X_i=\begin{cases} 1 & :\textrm{the card drawn on turn $i$ was not drawn previously}\\0 & : \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then the *expected number of unique cards drawn in $k$ turns* is: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k X_i) & = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \mathsf P(X_i{=}1)
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac 1{k^{i-1}} \\ & = \dfrac{k-k^{1-k}}{k-1}
\end{align}$$

(Is this *actually* what you are looking for?   Your wording is a little unclear.)

---

If you want the *expected number of draws until all $k$ cards have been drawn at least once*, then, the expected number of draws until the first distinct card is draw is $1$, then the expected number of draws until the second distinct card is drawn is $\tfrac{k}{k-1}$, and so on, and finally the expected number of draws until the last distinct card is drawn is $k$; each stage is a geometric random variable with success probability $\frac{k-i+1}{k}$

$\mathsf E(N) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{k}{k-i+1} = k H_k$ where $H_k$ is the $k$-th Harmonic number.

See [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I am exactly looking for this. And I have calculated out that P(X2 = n) = (1 / k) ^ (n - 1) * ( (k - 1) / k) where k is the total number of cards. Do I need to include up to infinity in my calculation for expectation?

Comment: When I try to calculate the expectation of X2, I got a summation to infinity. And when I try to add up all the X2, X3 up to Xk, I got another summation. Where the final expectation become a summation of summation. But I do not know how to simplify it...

Comment: @HONG I suggest you edit the question to show the calculations you have made. Use MathJax (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is hard to say how to simplify your summation of a summation when you don't show the sums. We can try to guess what those sums may be but it is not completely clear what you're trying to do, so we could easily guess wrong.